# How do I make my MacBook Pro (mid 2009) running Lion, DNLA compatible?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I would like to view photos and videos on my smart TV.  I do not do video games and am not real technically knowledgeable so need answer in layman's terms.

Comment: Have you done anything beyond posting a question here in terms of researching a solution to your issue? (i.e. Google searches, etc..)

Comment: @Bushwhacker Could you please add the software/links you already found to the question? It might help to understand what you consider to be technotalk.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to install [p3mediaserver](https://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/downloads/detail?name=pms-macosx-1.72.0.dmg) which is free and does provide DNLA functionality. Despite its name it not only works with a PS3 on the other end.

To install just download the .dmg linked above, double-click to open and drag the application to your /Applications folder. All folders are shared by default, but this can (and should) be restricted in the settings.

---

OTOH you might be better off with investing in an Apple TV box which makes the whole sharing thing much easier.

Comment: In response to Mort, yes, I did several google searches and found several suggestions mentioning many different softwares all using technotalk that I couldn't really understand.  Thanks to patrix for your suggestion.  I will try p3mediaserver.